# Reading bytes with PySerial: Empty results (Java works)

Tags: python, byte, pyserial

I am trying to read bytes from a digital meter via PySerial. It all works with Processing/Java. But i need it to port to Raspberry Pi.

While Java receives the correct bytes, Python does not receive anything at all. The digital meter simply sends 16 bytes delimited by 13.

Working Java / Processing code (receives byte array):

```
import processing.serial.*;
String portName = "/dev/tty.PL2303-00001004";
myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
...
if ( myPort.available() > 0)
{
  byte[] inBuffer = new byte[16];
  myPort.readBytesUntil(13, inBuffer);
  println("Buffer: " + inBuffer.length);
}
```

Not working Python code (receives nothing / ''):

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.PL2303-00001004', 9600, timeout=None) # tried different timeout
print(ser.isOpen())

while True:
    tmp = ser.read()
    print tmp
    print tmp.__len__()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Reading an Arduino Board with this Python code works fine.

**Solution: ser.setDTR(1) got it working!**

Comment: What doesn't work about it?

Comment: PySerial does not receive anything.
ser.read() prints
''
While Java receives the right bytes.

Comment: Have you tried changing other settings such as parity, RTS/CTS flow control, etc?

Comment: ser.setDTR(1) got it working! Thanks!

Comment: Put your comment as an answer, and try to explain why it works. In this way others with the same or similar problem will benefit.

Comment: "Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking."
I'll answer it later.

Answer (score 1):

ser.setDTR(1) got it working! Thanks!

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.PL2303-00001004', 9600, timeout=None) # tried different timeout
ser.setDTR(1)
print(ser.isOpen())

while True:
    tmp = ser.read()
    print tmp
    print tmp.__len__()
    time.sleep(1)
```